# Swiftui Textfield not updating when value changes

Tags: swiftui, state, textfield

I have a textfield on a form where user can type value, but I would also like to update the content of the textfield with a button.

Here is my code :

```
struct test: View {
@State private var amount: Double = 0.0

var body: some View {
    Form {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Amount EUR")
                Spacer()
                TextField("Type amount", value: $amount, format: .number)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            }
            
            Text("Set MAX (999)")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("before tap \(amount )")
                    amount = 999
                    print("after tap \(amount)")
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

When I just launch  the app, the first tap on the Text updates the textfield with 999, but after it does not work anymore.
The `amount` value is correctly updated but the textfield does not reflect the change.

Would you have an explanation ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is simply that `TextFields` don't update while they are in focus. To solve this problem, you need to incorporate a `@FocusState` in to the view, and cause the `TextField` to lose focus right before updating the variable. You can test it in your own view by tapping your `Text` prior to tapping in to the `TextField`. You will see it updates just fine.

```
struct ButtonUpdateTextField: View {
    @State private var amount: Double = 0.0
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool // <-- add here
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Amount EUR")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Type amount", value: $amount, format: .number)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .focused($isFocused) // <-- add here
                }
                
                Text("Set MAX (999)")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("before tap \(amount )")
                        isFocused = false // <-- add here
                        amount = 999
                        print("after tap \(amount)")
                    }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we know if there's a good reason why TextField won't update if binding changes while they are in focus?   Surprisingly hard to find this info.  Anyway, this workaround didn't quite work for me as-is -- I had to use asyncAfter() to delay the update of the bound variable until after the focus change had time to take effect.  Still, very helpful answer thank you!

Comment: This also did not work for me 'as is'. Starting from `asyncAfter` I was able to strip it down to simply updating the binding value in simple `DispatchQueue.main.async`. No need to use `@FocusState`, just `DispatchQueue.main.async { amount = newValue }`

Comment: I'm looking for this answer for almost two days. Adding `DispatchQueue.main.async` fixed my issue. Thank you so much!