# How to programmatically erase an optional TextField value in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In this sample I want to clear the value of a TextField with a custom button. However, the button action (`value = nil`) seems to be ignored. Why?

[Sample video](https://i.imgur.com/YtXGmF8.mp4)

Tested on Xcode 14 beta 6 (iOS 16).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value: Int?
    @FocusState var focused: Bool
    
    var buttonOpacity: Double {
        focused && value != nil ? 1 : 0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            HStack {
                TextField("Value", value: $value, format: .number.grouping(.never))
                    .focused($focused)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    value = nil
                } label: {
                    Label("Erase", systemImage: "multiply")
                        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                        .imageScale(.medium)
                        .symbolVariant(.circle.fill)
                        .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
                        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
                .opacity(buttonOpacity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71259654/swiftui-textfield-not-updating-when-value-changes try to add  focused = false before value = nil

Comment: Unfortunately I tried but it doesn't work either :(

Comment: not always. Just on first tap. On second tap the textfield value changed properly

Comment: What version of Xcode/iOS are you using please? This fix (i.e. adding `focused = false` before `value = nil`) is not working with Xcode 14 beta 6 (iOS 16).