TextField not updating until another TextField is updated
I'm encountering an issue with SwiftUI where a TextField does not update immediately when text is entered. Instead, the update only appears after another TextField is updated. I'm using @State variables to manage the text for each TextField.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amount = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("inputNumber", text: $amount)
                .foregroundColor(amount.count < 10 ? .red : .primary)
            
            TextField("inputNumber", text: $amount)
                .foregroundColor(amount.count < 10 ? .red : .primary)
        }
    }

}

the issue

As far as I can see from the documentation, KMM cannot integrate into SwiftUI this way. You must create a UIViewRepresentable.

Your knowledge is incorrect. it is possible

Okay not necessarily a UIViewRepresentable. You can also wrap it in an ObservableObject - anything that SwiftUI can observe. See this for how to do this with an additional pod.

The point is, you must change the design of ZenoTextField.

thank you, you are not answering my question

AFAIK, a TextField does not refresh when it is in focus.
A workaround is to use another var, as shown in the example code.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amount = ""
    @State private var color = Color.primary // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("inputNumber", text: $amount)
                .foregroundColor(color) // <-- here
                .onChange(of: amount) {
                    color = amount.count < 10 ? .red : .primary  // <-- here
                }
        }
    }
}


could you add more details "TextField does not refresh when it is in focus."

I admit that the explanation a TextField does not refresh when it is in focus is a
bit tenuous. I read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71259654/swiftui-textfield-not-updating-when-value-changes
But I could not find a definitive documentation on the subject.
My approach does work, but the reason why the original code did not,
is not clear to me. My guess is, something to do with synchronization.
I have seen this behaviour mentioned on SO before, but I cannot find a reference to it.

I hope apple know about this

It's only been 5 years for SwiftUI to be this good. We
need to wait another 10 or 20 for it to be reasonable, not to mention the documentation.
